# Inserir valor de consulta do Mysql em um array separado por vírgula

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando inserir um resultado de um consulta feita no `MySql` em array separado por vírgula, mas estou com dificuldades para faze-lo.

Eu tenho essa consulta:

```
SELECT 
  `gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdUnicoop
FROM
  `gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`
WHERE
  (`gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdUsuario = 3803) AND 
  (`gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdSistema = 5)
```

Essa consulta me resulta isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei algo como isso:

```
    $Registros = array (
    ...
    );
```

Estou tentando jogar esses valores nesse array separado por vírgula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blz vamos lá:
Pelo que entendi, sua consulta e conexao estao ok.
Basta usar o mysqli_fetch_array(), ele tem como tipo de retorno um array.

```
<?php
   $Conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ServerUsuario", "ServerSenha");
   $Query = "SELECT `gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdUnicoop
             FROM `gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`
             WHERE (`gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdUsuario = 3803) 
             AND (`gasUsuarioUnicoopSis`.IdSistema = 5)";
   $Consulta = mysqli_query($Conexao, $Query);

   $Registros = mysqli_fetch_array($Consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Para usar o Array, basta declarar o índice desejado.
O echo() é só uma das possibilidades.

O mysqli_fetch_array() recebe dois parâmetros em sua chamada: a string com a consulta e o tipo de identificação do campo.

MYSQLI_ASSOC: -voce pode usar o nome da coluna para localizar dados.

```
echo("Primeiro Campo:".$Registros[IdUsuario]. " Segundo Campo:". $Registros[IdSistema]);
```

MYSQLI_NUM: ->voce pode usar um numero para identificar o índice.

```
echo("Primeiro Campo:".$Registros[0]. " Segundo Campo:". $Registros[1]);
```

MYSQLI_BOTH: ->voce pode usar tanto numero como o nome.

```
echo("Primeiro Campo:".$Registros[IdUsuario]. " Segundo Campo:". $Registros[1]);
```